# What status code to return in a REST API for uneditable login field

Tags: rest

Once a user is created, his login cannot be changed. On UI the login field is just grayed-out and non-editable. If this same functionality is exposed via REST API, what HTTP status code (and what error message) to return if someone tries to edit the user and change his login?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say when they do the PUT to change the login return a 405 method not allowed.

You could always use a 400

You should also provide details on why they got a 405 or 400.

Comment: I think 405 won't fit here. The struct you send to edit a user contains all the user details (including the login). So PUT should definitely be allowed to change other details. It's only when you send the struct that only contains the login parameter the system should reject the PUT.

Comment: Then use a 400 with the details of what they did wrong in the request.

Answer (score 0):

For unauthorized access you could return an HTTP status code of 401. What authentication method are you using in the API (example: basic, digest...)? Are you letting users register through the API? A lot of services have a separate registration process through a web application that can control the registration process and do not expose registration in the API. Once they are registered they use the credentials created during the registration process for authentication and authorization for using the API.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a `403 Forbidden`, ideally with a struct carrying an error message i.e. `{"errorReason": "Login cannot be modified."}`.